# jQuery Datatable - Error message from ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, datatables

```
 "ajax": {
            "url": url,
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json",
            "data": { id: id}
            //,
            //"success": function (data) {
            //    if (!data.data)
            //        ShowErrorMessage(data.message);
            //}
        },
        "columns": [
                { "data": "ID" },
                { "data": "Name" },
                { "data": "Time" }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": 2,
            "data": "Time",
            "render": function (data) {
                return (ToJavaScriptDate(data));
            }
        }]
    });
```

Above the sample code, which will populate a datatable using ajax GET call. The issue here is, sometimes I will return a valid error message instead of table data from ajax response.

So when ever there is data in data.data, I need to populate the table and if data is not there, I need to populate the data.message as custom error message. Here both the calls are success calls but whether to display the table content or error message depends.

I tried "success" attribute but I am not sure how to manually bind the columns when there is data in data.data

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.emptyTable

Comment: @AlivetoDie I understand I can go for empty table message. The complexity here is I need to populate the message I got from ajax response as empty table message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to use [`language.emptyTable`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.emptyTable) option.

However since you want to use message from the Ajax response, there is a hacky way to do it.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {
       url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/if7vf',
       dataSrc: function(d){
          if(d.data.length === 0){
             var settings = $('#example').DataTable().settings()[0];
             settings.oLanguage.sEmptyTable = d.message;
          }

          return d.data;
       }
    }
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/fj5629sx/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks. Please help to  manipulate a particular column E.g. as mentioned in question ("Time") and few are hidden columns

Comment: @TechJerk, if you want to have 1 data row if no data is available, then instead of setting `sEmptyTable` variable you could do something like `d.data.push({'ID': '', 'Name': '', 'Time': d.message})` to add 1 new row if there is no data.